# C++ Funtion template with flexible return type

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have been trying to implement a sanity check on inputs using template programming. My sanity check function looks as below

```
template<typename T> T getInput(std::string& _input) {
std::cin >> _input;
if(std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
    try{
        auto result=std::stoi(_input);
        return(result);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument& except) {
        std::cout << except.what() << "\n";
    }
}
else if(std::is_same<T, unsigned int>::value) {
    try{
        auto result=std::stoul(_input);
        return(result);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument& except) {
        std::cout << except.what() << "\n";
    }
}
else if(std::is_same<T, float>::value) {
    try{
        auto result=std::stof(_input);
        return(result);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument& except) {
        std::cout << except.what() << "\n";
    }
}
else if(std::is_same<T, std::string>::value) {
    auto result = _input;
    return(result);
}
else {
    std::cerr << "Unknown input type!\n";
    std::exit(1);
}
}
```

And i call the function in main as below

```
int main() {
std::string _input = "10";
std::cout << "Enter value:" <<  getInput<int>(_input) << '\n';
return(0);
```

}
This, however throws the following error.

```
error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to function return type 'int'
    return(result);
```

I am really not sure if I understand this error correctly. Could someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction ?

Thank you!

Comment: if you can use C++17, you can use `if constexpr`; otherwise, I don't think it's possible what do you want.

Comment: could you please tell me why this isn't possible ? I dont  understand "the why" part.

Comment: The entire function must be type-correct, regardless of what type `T` is. You can't return a `std::string` from a function that returns `int`.

Comment: But I dont necessarily return a string . For the int type I am returning an int using stoi() function. That is what is confusing me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple `if` still requires that branch is valid even if not selected (your function does return all of `int`/`unsigned int`/`float`/`string`).

`if constexpr` allows to "discard" not selected branches (but requires compile time condition (that you have)).

```
template<typename T>
T getInput(std::string& _input) {
    std::cin >> _input;

    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
        try{
            auto result=std::stoi(_input);
            return(result);
        }
        catch(std::invalid_argument& except) {
            std::cout << except.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, unsigned int>::value) {
        try{
            auto result=std::stoul(_input);
            return(result);
        }
        catch(std::invalid_argument& except) {
            std::cout << except.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
    // ...

}
```

Before C++17, you have to use other ways as specialization, tag dispatching, ...

```
template<typename T> T getInput(std::string& _input);

template<> int getInput(std::string& _input)
{
    std::cin >> _input;

    try {
        auto result=std::stoi(_input);
        return(result);
    } catch(std::invalid_argument& except) {
        std::cout << except.what() << "\n";
    }
}

template<> unsigned int getInput(std::string& _input)
{
    try{
        auto result=std::stoul(_input);
        return(result);
    } catch(std::invalid_argument& except) {
        std::cout << except.what() << "\n";
    }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Hi @Jarod42, that solves it. Although I am getting the following warning. `warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`. Could you please explain as to why I get this? Thanks

Comment: From my understanding, it appears that this warning is thrown because of absence of return statement in the `else {}` condition.

Comment: In case of exception, you indeed no return anything.